# how can i implement "or" in scheme in different ways

Tags: scheme

I am trying to learn scheme. My question is how can I implement "or" with 2 elements in scheme without using "or". I tried to so `(id (!A) B A` but the i get `A` twice, anyone has a different idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identifier `or` is a syntactic keyword (aka 'syntax') and thus has special evaluation rules.  (Just like in 'C' - syntax is special.)  To implement `or` you need to define its syntax:

```
(define-syntax or
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((or a b)
     (let ((a-evaled a))    ;; only eval 'a' once
       (if a-evaled a-evaled b)))))
```

[Note that 'syntax' isn't normally a beginner's topic.  But, you need syntax for `or`.]